Fix systemd ordering cycle with NFS automount, Nebula and local-fs.target
I want to mount an NFS share over Nebula (an overlay VPN similar to Tailscale). I want to do this because this machine is sometimes connected over wireless and the IP address changes, breaking my NFS. This is all working fine, except that on boot I receive warnings about an ordering cycle with systemd:
[    2.711253] systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Found ordering cycle on nfs-mythie.automount/start
[    2.711257] systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Found dependency on snap.nebula.daemon.service/start
[    2.711260] systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Found dependency on network.target/start
[    2.711262] systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Found dependency on wpa_supplicant.service/start
[    2.711265] systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Found dependency on basic.target/start
[    2.711267] systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Found dependency on sockets.target/start
[    2.711269] systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Found dependency on cups.socket/start
[    2.711272] systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
[    2.711274] systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Found dependency on local-fs.target/start
[    2.711277] systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job nfs-mythie.automount/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with local-fs.target/start

My automount for the NFS share is:
[Unit]
Description=nfs automount for Mythie  
Requires=snap.nebula.daemon.service
After=snap.nebula.daemon.service

[Automount]
Where=/nfs/mythie      
TimeoutIdleSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

The mount file, if it matters, is:
[Unit]
Description = nfs mount for Mythie over Nebula 
Requires=snap.nebula.daemon.service
After=snap.nebula.daemon.service

[Mount]
What=[Nebula IP]:[Mount on server] 
Where=/nfs/mythie  
Type=nfs
Options=defaults
TimeoutSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

The required Nebula service is:
[Unit]
# Auto-generated, DO NOT EDIT
Description=Service for snap application nebula.daemon
Requires=snap-nebula-115.mount
Wants=network.target
After=snap-nebula-115.mount network.target snapd.apparmor.service
X-Snappy=yes
[...]

and snap-nebula-115.mount is:
[Unit]
Description=Mount unit for nebula, revision 115
After=snapd.mounts-pre.target
Before=snapd.mounts.target

[Mount]
What=/var/lib/snapd/snaps/nebula_115.snap
Where=/snap/nebula/115
Type=squashfs
Options=nodev,ro,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide
LazyUnmount=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=snapd.mounts.target
WantedBy=multi-user.target

and snapd.mounts-pre.target is:
[Unit]
Description=Mounting snaps
RefuseManualStart=yes
After=zfs-mount.service
# Started from snapd.mounts.target
# X-Snapd-Snap: do-not-start

I see in the man page for systemd that:
       local-fs.target
           systemd-fstab-generator(3) automatically adds dependencies of
           type Before= to all mount units that refer to local mount
           points for this target unit. In addition, it adds
           dependencies of type Wants= to this target unit for those
           mounts listed in /etc/fstab that have the auto mount option
           set.

I am not seeing an explicit dependency cycle here, but I'm guessing that the issue is that local-fs.target requires mounting all the local filesystems, Nebula is wanting that done before starting and I've told my NFS automount that it requires Nebula. How should I fix this? Can I tell Systemd not to worry about the NFS automount as part of local-fs or something?
Thanks for any pointers.
